# How to make the swf load after all the images and text loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

My CMS system allows people to post some SWF's on my homepage however, sometimes there is a video which is included in the SWF (**not** two files like swf+flv). When the SWF video loads it uses up the bandwidth and so the page seems non-responsive for a while. Can I use jQuery to control all of the SWF's in a page that they load after the others are done; or maybe just load it after 3s?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should wrap your flash file in a `div` tag

```
<div id="image" align="center"> <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="281" height="28">
<param name="movie" value="whatever.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<embed src="contactb.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="281" height="28"></embed>
</object>
</div>
```

and use the following CSS code:

```
.image {
display: none;
}
```

then call at your last image declartion an `onload` event that will display the swf block

```
<img onload="document.getElementById('image').style.display = 'block'" src="whatever" />
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to fetch the `.swf` and add to the page dynamically. or,

---

Place the `html` for `.swf` just before the `</body>` tag with style as `display:none` and using JavaScript, add it to the proper node.

```
$.ready(function(){
   //move swf to proper place
});
```